# Use a laptop to convert VGA to HDMI

Tags: vga, hdmi, conversion

I have a laptop with both a VGA output and HDMI output and was wondering if I could use this to convert a HDMI input into a VGA output.

If this is possible how could it be done and if not why not?

Comment: @Brian Carlton is correct in his answer, but if you were really set on converting an HDMI signal to an analog VGA signal, you could use [this converter](http://www.amazon.com/PETHV-converter-3-5mm-Stereo-Converter/dp/B003O55U8K).

Answer (score 4):

No. Both ports are outputs, so you can't receive HDMI and output VGA.

Answer (score 1):

### No. Unfortunately.

HDMI specifies two types of devices, "sources" and "sinks". While HDMI implements the EIA/CEA-861 standards (which control the digital format of the audio and video -- and how the devices identify themselves to one-another), the data flow directions are specified in the HDMI standards itself.

This means that you must have different (almost mirror-image) hardware between a source (usually transmitting) and sink (usually receiving). The Intel Mobile 4 Chipset, for example, that is common in laptops does not include the HDMI sink capability (decoders, receivers, etc).